# MuscleCommandline not working in Biopython

Tags: python, biopython, sequence-alignment

I need to integrate my python script with the muscle tool for multiple sequence alignment. I followed the tutorial on Biopython, here there is my code:

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
muscle_exe = "muscle.exe"
in_file = "small.fasta"
out_file = "aligned.fasta"
muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(muscle_exe, input=in_file, out=out_file)

print(muscle_cline)
```

I am running it in correct folder with the renamed muscle.exe file. However, python does not output anything except the command and the file aligned.fasta is not created. 
I saw the old questions, but it seems that nobody has ever had this problem.
Muscle is working fine in the normal command line.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.Applications._Muscle.MuscleCommandline-class.html) is a bit confusing in my opinion. The `print` does not start muscle but just prints the command which would be executed. You could run muscle either by calling

```
stdout, stderr = muscle_cline()
```

or without BioPython

```
import subprocess
muscle_result = subprocess.check_output([muscle_exe, "-in", in_file, "-out", out_file])
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a way to view the output of the command in real-time, I mean as the command was launched in the commandline

Comment: Depends what you mean - you can tell MUSCLE to output to stdout, and using subprocess you can choose to capture stdout (which is what Biopython does for you) or let it just print to the terminal.

Comment: Also how would you clarify the docstring WITHOUT including ``stdout, stderr = muscle_cline()`` in the doctest example (since we use that in an automated test framework)?

Comment: Can't you make stdout/stderr a part of a function, distinct from other variables used? There's really no way around using predefined language.